# Access 2013, SQL, Update one row rather than one column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form that needs to only occasionally update a linked table. So I made a cmd button to run the following query. Trouble is, it updates the entire column in the destination table rather than a single row. How do I set this up to only update a single row?

```
UPDATE tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2
ON tbl2.ID = tbl1.ID SET tbl1.Field1 = [Forms]![Project Details]![txtCustomerName], 
tbl1.Field2 = [Forms]![Project Details]![txtCustomerNumber]
;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you missing some `where` criteria?  As written, this will update all rows in `tbl1` that have a matching record in `tbl2`.  Perhaps `where tbl1.id = [Forms]![Project Details]![Id]`?

Comment: declare a variable and use it to update each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sgeddes!

```
UPDATE tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2
ON tbl2.ID = tbl1.ID 
SET tbl1.Field1 = [Forms]![Project Details]![txtCustomerName], 
tbl1.Field2 = [Forms]![Project Details]![txtCustomerNumber]
;
```